# Перебор многомерного jagged массива

Tags: c#, массивы, for

Ребят, решил после js изучать С#, сразу возникли сложности. Необходимо перебрать двухмерный массив.

```
int[,] originalArray = new int[10, 10];

//filling array

for (int i = 0; i < originalArray.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < originalArray.GetLength(i); y++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(originalArray[i, y]);
    }

}
```

на первой итерации мы узнаем количество строк. во второй цикл передается непосредственно итая строка, длину которой я например могу не знать, каким образом ее определить? если например массивы будут разные, а не как в этом примере. В данном случае получается исключение, что индекс выходит за границы. 
Безусловно, можно было бы вынести эти значения в переменные, которые определяются выше, но хотелось именно так это реализовать.
Спасибо.

Comment: изначально была мысль в этот перебор включать и зубчатые массивы, но.. как я вспомнил, у них синтаксис другой, и редактирование или даже вывод элементов будет описываться по другому.... по тому остановился на методе getLength() с параметром 0 и 1

Comment: _каким образом ее определить?_ - например с помощью свойства [Length](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: `int[n, m]` - это многомерный массив - все строки одной длины. `int[n][m]` - это jagged (изрезанный, зубчатый) массив - строки могут быть разной длины.

Comment: @Grundy да, безусловно, но я не могу определить длину самой строки в отдельности этим свойством, оно определяет только длину всего массива, разве что length/getLength(0). но это как мне кажется менее удобно. смущает то, что например я не могу написать вот так: array[1].length или если более точно array[i].length, когда длина строки не известна.

Comment: если у тебя jagged array,  как ты указал в заголовке - то можешь :)

Comment: @Grundy заголовок отредактировали за меня)

Comment: @AndreyRudoy, надо было откатить правку. из-за нее по сути смысл вопроса поменялся:)

Comment: @Grundy Возник еще вопрос, не хочу плодить темы.... есть созданный и заполненый массив, хочу его элементами наполнить новый, такого же размера змейкой. Элементы с исходного выдергиваются через форИч, в котором 2 вложенных цикла первый перебирает строки, второй индексы в строке и заполняет i,j значением item. но выходит так, что для каждого элемента item цикл с итератором j заполняет всю линию. Есть может где то информация по подобному перебору? Точнее даже по осуществлению такой задумки

Comment: @AndreyRudoy, примеры заполнения можно посмотреть тут: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/804963/186999

Answer (score 3):

c разным количеством элементов во вложенных массивах

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[][] arr = new int[3][];

            arr[0] = new int[5] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 };
            arr[1] = new int[4] { 2, 4, 6, 8 };
            arr[2] = new int[3] { 12, 34, 46 };

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Element({0}): ", i);

                for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0}{1}", arr[i][j], j == (arr[i].Length - 1) ? "" : " ");
                }
                System.Console.WriteLine();            
            }
        }
    }
}

// тоже самое через foreach

foreach(var item in arr)
{
     foreach(var element in item)
     {
         Console.Write(element.ToString() + " ");
     }
     Console.WriteLine();
 }


//`len` - длинна (можно сделать чтобы вводить) ну и далее два раза обход 
//1 - заполнение 
//2 - вывод



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int len = 5;
            Random r = new Random();
            int[,] originalArray = new int[len, len];
            for (int i = 0 ; i < originalArray.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0 ; j < originalArray.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    originalArray[i,j] = r.Next(0,100);
                }
            }


            for (int i = 0 ; i < originalArray.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0 ; j < originalArray.GetLength(1); j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(originalArray[i,j].ToString() + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: чем данный код отличается от кода в вопросе?

Comment: @Grundy отличается... у автора вопроса во внутреннем цикле в `GetLength(i)` вставлен счетчик наружного цикла, а надо сделать как в ответе.

Comment: сейчас я так и сделал. работоспособность есть. Вопрос заключается в чем почему например нет возможности указать там итый элемент. Например и в моем коде, и в Вашем размерность массива известна заранее, но если например такой возможности нет. Гипотетически предположим, что это зубчатый массив, в котором я не могу заранее знать длину

Comment: почему вставлен счетчик наружного цикла? по тому как границей должно быть количество элементов итой строки. в целом да, так как сетки не зубчатая, getlength(1) будет равен для каждой из строк. Но если например они не равны....

Comment: @AndreyRudoy мне не понятно что именно не равно у вас...приведите пример просто массива двумерного, который вам надо обойти. В вашем вопросе представленна квадратная матрица. Вы имеете ввиду если она будет 4x6 - не равны, или как?

Comment: например если это зубчатый массив. когда 4 строки будут длинной в 4-5-6-7. Например так. Каким методом перебрать его, если во внутренний цикл не передается переменная, в данном случае это итератор, с внешнего? Как тогда перебрать i-тую строку? forEach не берем во внимание.

Comment: @AndreyRudoy я обновил ответ...думаю `foreach` - это то что вам нужно

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц да, спасибо. вот как раз, смутило, что метод применяемый для зубчатого массива не работает с обычным) Наверное это пройдет со временем, после того как забуду понятие массива с js)